# Not a what am I, but a what is it, be sure

Tags: riddle

> Again I have come to a place I just was.
>
> Enter it, I have, just because.
>
> I bought a shovel, that I wish to give back,
>
> Because I’m not allowed to bury Uncle Jack.
>
> I was given a key, it was not for a door,
>
> Not a what am I, but a what is it, be sure.

Comment: Is it linked with computer accessories/ peripherals such as key-boards ?

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Zipcode

As

Again I have come to a place I just was

> Posts with return stamps attached (usually not a case though!) come back to place where they belong to!

Enter it, I have, just because

> without which post could not be delivered (in time, sometimes)

I bought a shovel, that I wish to give back,

> To be  explored ...

Because I’m not allowed to bury Uncle Jack.

> To be explored ...

I was given a key, it was not for a door,

> The key (code) is for a place/home and not for a door (not a physical one!)

Not a what am I, but a what is it, be sure.

> A zipcode by itself is useless, if it is not having proper value (5 or 9 digits)

Comment: Random suggestions off the top of my head: "I bought a shovel, that I wish to give back" -> a shovel that has to be returned due to incorrect shipping; "Because I’m not allowed to bury Uncle Jack" -> you cannot send ("bury" into a package) people through the mail system.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> SSH (Secure SHell)?

Again I have come to a place I just was.

> A typical use of SSH is to access a (probably headless) computer that you own, where you "just were" setting up.

Enter it, I have, just because.

> Entering the computer via SSH.

I bought a shovel, that I wish to give back,

> This might be tools like Metasploitable (the shovel), which are used to test / exploit systems, which you wish to give back because... (see next clue)

Because I’m not allowed to bury Uncle Jack.

> Might refer to not being able to attack (bury) an SSH server (Uncle Jack) by law / because the program is so well protected.

I was given a key, it was not for a door,

> A key in cryptography is a special value that is used to encrypt and unencrypt data. The key in reference is the SSH public key, which is used to SSH into a computer without entering a password or passphrase.

Not a what am I, but a what is it, be sure.

> SSH is merely a protocol, and as such, it is up to individual programs (such as OpenSSH) to establish how it actually executes.